# Ch or CINT on Macports?

Tags: c, macports

Does Macports have Ch and Cint (C interactive interpreters) as available ports? I can't seem to find them through port search.

Failing which, can anyone recommend what is the easiest way to install either Ch or Cint on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an effort by CERN developers to port their Cint to Clang: nicely named [Clint](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling).

Although I think CINT works fine on Mac: see [here](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) for build/install instructions

Comment: ok. thanks for the info - so there isn't an automated way of building these interactive shells yet. got to manually build them I suppose...

Comment: calvinx: I think your best bet for an automated installer is [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/production-version-530) itself, which uses CINT, but I don't know how different it is from the pure thing. Edit: Macports seem to redistribute ROOT, if that's easier for you.

Comment: Hmm. Was browsing the cern site but didn't notice this link. Thanks for pointing that out! :-)